# Having exposed System.Data.DataTable into JS via ClearScript how do I express its objects for TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, system.data, clearscript

So I have an amped up JavaScript scripting environment in my application provided by `ClearScript`.

It dawned on me that I could use `TypeScript` to write hopefully better code and for the most part that's working out.

At the top of each script I have a import statement like this

```
import {...} from "../d/global";
```

with the exports in global.d.ts like

```
export class Progress {
  stop(): Progress;
  start(): Progress;
  toString(): string;
}
```

My problems are in how to describe the objects that I've pulled in from System.Data.

For example the following gives me a `DataTable` in `parents`

```
  var parents = DB.DTEval(
      new SQLStoredProcedureCall("taskRuleSet_49_see46")
      .numericParam("@XwCheckControllerFK", CONTROLLER_RECORD.XwCheckControllerID)
      .toString());
```

`DataTable` has `.Rows` which can receive a parameter and return a `DataRow` object

```
parents.Rows(0).Item("...")
```

or not receive parameter but be available for querying about other things, like Count

```
parents.Rows.Count
```

How do I express these various behaviours in a `TypeScript` declaration?

Comment: In TS one uses [Interfaces](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/interfaces.html) to define the shape of an object (and function types). They work as a contract that must be fulfilled by the implementer.